# Getting the source for JDK 1.6.0_23 to debug JVM/hotspot garbage collection

Tags: debugging, java

Just out of curiosity, I'd like to debug the JVM 1.6.0_23 Garbage collection on Win64 platform.

Currently using Oracle JDK 1.6.0_23,

1. can I just grab the source from [openjdk6-b23](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/promoted/b23/openjdk-6-src-b23-05_jul_2011.tar.gz) and build it, and then
2. replace the original Oracle JDK jvm.dll with the one I built,
3. Use visual studio to attach to a running java process
4. set a break point and do step over etc etc

Will the above steps work ?

Comment: You have over 50 questions without an accepted answer. Perhaps you can follow up answers so they can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the standard debugging options to trace what the GC is doing first.
What exactly are you trying to debug?

The code base for the OpenJDK is large enough that trying to debug it is like to take a long time to be able to figure out what is going on. Otherwise its an application like any other and you should be able to step through the code.

Comment: I'm keen to learn about JVM and garbage collection and am curious about the code too, also at the moment i'm trying to figure out how JVM reclaims weak references.

Comment: I suggest you read the Java source for Weak references and the many articles on this topic first. You could easily spend a month reading the code before you have much idea what it is all doing. The code was written by a number of professors over many years. Don't underestimate the time it would take to understand it this way.